# HTML Javascript event handling added in a method

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, dom-events

```
var p=0;
function addLine() {
    var tb = document.getElementById("tb");
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
    var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
    var td3 = document.createElement("TD");
    var textF = document.createElement("INPUT");
    textF.value = "Add image URL";
    td1.appendChild(textF);
    var bt = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    bt.id = p;
    p++;
    var text = document.createTextNode("Load Image");
    td2.appendChild(bt);
    bt.appendChild(text);
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.alt = "No image loaded yet";
    td3.appendChild(img);
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    tb.appendChild(row);
    row.children[1].children[0].onClick = load();
}

function load() {
        console.log("in method");
        //var bt = window.event.target;
        var i = 0;
        var tb = document.getElementById("tb");
        tb.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].alt = "Image not found";
        tb.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].src = tb.rows[i].cells[0].children[0].value;
}
```

I want to add an event handler to each button generated, I have also tried to use the `addEventListener()`, but nothing seems to work. And for some reason I  get the console output "in method" when the `addLine()` method is activated. I also want to have the event object created by the event in order to get the target.

Comment: because it is `onclick` not `onClick` and you are calling load and assigning what it returns to the onclick event listener.

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="functionName()">Some Text</button>

Comment: But I also need to pass the event that caused as an argument to the method, to be able to get the target of it.

Answer (score 0):

add this on end of *addLine()* function:

jQuery:

```
$(bt).on('click', function(){
 /* your code here*/
})
```

js:

```
bt.addEventListener('click', function(){
/* your code here */
}, false)
```

or:

```
 bt.addEventListener('click', load)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems is the event is case sensitive so it needs to be all lowercase. And you are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the event listener.

So you need to make it all lowercase and drop the ()

```
row.children[1].children[0].onclick = load;
```

or

```
bt.addEventistener("click", load);
```